# UML-conform diagram or alternative to illustrate project dependencies

Tags: dependencies, uml

I have a Java framework that has a bunch of dependencies to libraries/projects (around 10). I want to illustrate these dependencies using some UML diagram, but in my inexperience with UML it seems to me that none of the structural diagrams fit for this purpose. What would be the best way to illustrate these dependencies using UML or an alternative?

Comment: What is that experience that makes you think UML is not fit for such dependency display?

Comment: It says inexperience.

Comment: What do you propose?

Comment: Oh, I misread. Go with Christophe's answer....

Answer (score 3):

You may use for this purpose a [component diagram](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/what-is-component-diagram/):

- The independent libraries and projects would be components.
- The dependencies can be precisely represented through the provided/required interfaces.
- Up to you to decide whether to show the library as one black-box component, or whether to show more detailed view on sub-components.

Another alternative could be to use a [package diagram](https://sparxsystems.com/resources/tutorials/uml2/package-diagram.html):

- packages are namespaces. Usually, it’s used for organizing modeling elements.
- But  you could easily use it to organize elements of your design such as the libraries and projects. You could even make a mapping to your java packages, and show their dependencies.